# std::map::iterator decrement on single element

Tags: c++, visual-c++, gcc, stl, stdmap

What should std::map iterator decrement return, if there's only single element in the map? Here's the sample code

```
#include <map>
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    std::map<int, int> m;
    m.insert(std::make_pair(1, 1));
    //std::map<int, int>::iterator it = m.begin();
    std::map<int, int>::iterator it = m.upper_bound(0);
    printf("isbegin: %d\n", it == m.begin());
    --it;
    bool isend = it == m.end();
    printf("isend: %d\n", isend);
}
```

On Windows it will print isend: 1, on Linux with g++ 4.6 it will print isend: 0.

The question: is the decrement above really a case of UB? and if not then what result is correct - Windows or Linux one?

UPDATE: modified code to show that upper_bound is called

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8533875/substraction-or-decrement-random-access-iterator-pointing-to-begin

Comment: Well, in real app the iterator is returned from upper_bound(), does the related Q still apply?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Decrementing something to the element before begin() doesn't make sense. This is undefined behavior and there is no correct or incorrect answer.

Comment: In real app the iterator is returned from upper_bound, so decrementing "some iterator" is illegal until we check that it's not equal to begin()?

Comment: It is not "illegal", but undefined. But yes, you should always be sure you're not decrementing a pointer that points to begin(). If you do so, you have no guarantee for what happens, even if you increment it back to begin()

Answer (score 2):

for an iterator `r` the operation `--r` is valid if before the operation is done there exists `s` such that `r == ++s` and after the operation is done `r` is dereferenceable. (§24.2.6 Bidirectional.iterators )

Since begin() returns an iterator to the first element of the container there is no element `s` which can be incremented to get to `r` so this is undefined.