# Is std::vector::begin() - 1 undefined?

Tags: c++, stl, iterator, portability

I need to iterate over some elements in backward order and I'm using:

```cpp
for ( /* ... */ it = vec.end() - 1, end = vec.begin() ; it >= end ; --it ) {
    // ...
```

I now that [`end() - 1`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5322104/how-portable-is-end-iterator-decrement) is defined for some containers, including vector, but now I need to know if begin decrement is also defined.

## EDIT

I don't know if I could use reverse_iterator, because I'll need to pass these iterators as parameters to std::vector::erase and from the documentation, it looks that they are different types.

Comment: Yes, and why would you need `begin() - 1`?

Comment: You could use `rbegin` and `rend` instead.

Comment: You can only _increment_ iterators unequal to `end`, or decrement iterators unequal  to `begin`. Fully symmetrical, simple rule.

Comment: Look at: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8533875/substraction-or-decrement-random-access-iterator-pointing-to-begin

Comment: "*I now that end() - 1 is defined for some containers*" No it isn't. It is only defined if `begin() != end()`.

Comment: Thanks @DieterLücking, I'll try to close my own question.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Yes, it is undefined.

If you want to iterate over elements in reverse, just use [`rbegin`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/rbegin) and [`rend`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/rend). They're reverse iterators, designed explicitly for this purpose. If you need to get a standard iterator from the reverse iterator, you can use the [`base` member function](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/reverse_iterator/base) on the iterator.

Comment: I don't know if I could use reverse_iterator, because I'll need to pass these iterators as parameters to std::vector::erase and from the documentation, it looks that they are different types.

Comment: Thank you. It looks like that I'll leave UB land. :)

Answer (score 4):

It is undefined behaviour. But why not use reverse iterators [rbegin()](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/rbegin) and [rend()](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/rend)?

```
std::vector<int> vec{0,1,2,3,4}
for (auto it = vec.rbegin(); it != vec.rend(); ++it) 
{
  std::cout << *it << " ";
}
std::cout << std::endl;
```

output

> 4 3 2 1 0

Comment: I don't know if I could use reverse_iterator, because I'll need to pass these iterators as parameters to std::vector::erase and from the documentation, it looks that they are different types

Comment: @vinipsmaker you should probably not be calling erase inside an iterator loop anyway. Maybe you should explain what you are trying to achieve. If it is too different from just iterating backwards, then it should be a different question.

Comment: if I can decrement begin, problem is solved. It looks, from the other question, that this behaviour is undefined, but there a lot of reasons why this must work, unless compiler wants to put an `if` to bug code relying on this behaviour and, together with this `if`, unnecessarily killing performance.

Comment: PS.: And reverse iteration is required, because iterators to elements beyond the removed range are invalidated.

Comment: @vinipsmaker there are no special `if` required, and you can typically type `--begin()`. For e.g. for `std::vector` it will simply do a pointer decrement). However, even for a C-array, pointing to one-before-the-beginning is undefined behavior, even without dereferencing. Undefined behavior includes that your code will work, except e.g. when you give a live demo :-)