# Iterating past the front of doubly linked list

Tags: c++, list, c++11, iterator, std

```
std::list<my_type> my_list;
std::list<my_type>::iterator my_iter = my_list.begin();
std::list<my_type>::iterator my_prev = std::prev(my_iter);
```

What is the value of my_prev?
Is it `my_list.rend()`, even though it is technically a different type?
How to check for such condition besides `my_iter == my_list.begin()`?

Comment: related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8533875/substraction-or-decrement-random-access-iterator-pointing-to-begin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to C++11 standard:

```
24.4.4 Iterator operations [iterator.operations]  
§ 7
template <class BidirectionalIterator>  
BidirectionalIterator prev(BidirectionalIterator x,  
typename std::iterator_traits<BidirectionalIterator>::difference_type n = 1);  
Effects: Equivalent to advance(x, -n); return x;
```

In the same section, but §2 and §3

```
template <class InputIterator, class Distance>  
void advance(InputIterator& i, Distance n);  
Requires: n shall be negative only for bidirectional and random access iterators.
Effects: Increments (or decrements for negative n) iterator reference i by n.
```

Then, for decrementing bidirectional iterators:

```
24.2.6 Bidirectional iterators
Expression  Return type Operational       Assertion/note
                          semantics     pre-/post-condition

                                        pre: there exists s such that
--r         X&                          r == ++s.
                                        post: r is dereferenceable.
                                        --(++r) == r.
                                        --r == --s implies r == s.
                                        &r == &--r.
```

---

So, it looks like (or at least I couldn't find more relevant part from the standard), that this behavior is not defined.

I'd suggest you to maintain this situation and be careful with `my_iter`'s value, before passing it to `std::prev`.

Comment: You're right, it's undefined behavior.  It happens to work with some list implementations but is not a good idea in any case.

Comment: It appears that it is a good idea precede a call to std::prev with a check for the argument to be != begin()