# Why this arr[0] is not equal to arr+0?

Tags: c

Hi I got confused to get the explanation for this below, can anyone explain it to me? Thanks in advance.

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main(){
    char *arr,c;
    arr = &c;

    arr++;
    *arr = 'a';

    arr++;
    *arr = 'b';

    arr++;
    *arr = 'c';

    arr--;
    arr--;

    printf("\narr 1 = %c",arr);
    printf("\narr 2 = %c",arr[1]);
    printf("\narr 3 = %c",arr[2]);
    getch();
    return 1;
    }
```

Output is :
arr 1 = a
arr 2 = b
arr 3 = c

but if the change the line:

```
printf("\narr 1 = %c",arr);
```

with

```
printf("\narr 1 = %c",arr[0]);
```

Now Output is:
arr 1 =  
arr 2 = b
arr 3 = c

why 'a' is not getting printed.?

*For all those who are questioning the program as bad coding.. I know its not a good coding practice to use pointer like this,  But my question is why arr[0] is not printing anything where as arr[1] & arr[2] is printing what is assigned?

Comment: You have a more severe problem which is that you have only one `char` but you're attempting to  modify 3 different `char`s.

Comment: Undefined behaviour, after the first `arr++`, you point to no memory you own.

Comment: I don't understand the downvotes. I'm agree that the code is very bad. But the guy tried something and it didn't work as he expected. IMHO the question is very legitimate and doesn't deserve downvote.

Comment: @LucM "Output is : argc = a argc = b argc = c" is simply not true. I downvote questions that claim nonsense as fact because they show a lack of effort on the asker's part (can't even be bothered to copy/paste actual results).

Comment: @EricPostpischil *Except for the change from “argc” to “arr 1”, et cetera* - that's exactly what I mean.

Comment: @EricPostpischil Those are the same thing as far as I'm concerned. "Here's my code and here are results I made up" and "here's my code and here are results from a different program" are equally unhelpful for debugging.

Comment: @melpomene: Of course conflicting information is unhelpful for debugging, but you stated earlier that your complaint was it showed a lack of effort. Would you like to delete your prior statement, since it appears to be inaccurate? (I see what you mean; I do find your conflicting information to be unhelpful, so I must agree with you.)

Comment: hey guys.. its my mistake, Please don't fight. I am going to edit it. :-)

Comment: As per your last paragraph - it's not bad coding practice, it's code that exhibits undefined behavior. Simple as that.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In the first version of the program, what likely happens is:

- The compiler puts `c` at some address on the the stack, say 1003 (a single byte).
- The compiler puts `arr` at some address on the stack, say 1004-1007 (four bytes).
- The statement `arr = &c;` puts the address of `c`, 1003, into `arr`.
- The statement `arr++;` adds one to `arr`, so it is now 1004 instead of 1003.
- The statement `*arr = 'a';` writes `'a'` to the place where `arr` points. This is now behavior that is **undefined** by the C standard. When `arr` was set to `&c`, there was only one byte in the object at that location, and the C standard does not guarantee what happens when you write to other locations after incrementing that address outside the object.
- As it happens in this instance, 1004 points into `arr`, so you are writing `'a'` into one of the bytes of `arr`. This horribly alters the address that was in `arr`.
- Then `arr++;` increments the address again, and `*arr = 'b';` writes `'b'` somewhere. We do not know where, because `arr` has a bad value in it.
- Then `arr++;` increments the address again, and `*arr = 'c';` writes `'c'` somewhere. We do not know where.
- Then `arr--;` and `arr--;` return the address to the value it had after `'a'` was written.
- Then the first `printf` call passes the value in `arr` to be printed with a “%c” specifier. “%c” is for printing a character, but the `arr` you pass it is a pointer. However, you previously wrote `'a'` into the pointer, so the value of the pointer has `'a'` in one of its bytes.
- As it happens, when the “%c” specifier is used with a pointer, this implementation of `printf` prints one of the bytes in the pointer value, in this case the same byte where you wrote `'a'`. So “a” is printed. **You cannot rely on this happening in other C implementations.** This happened in this case only because the compiler happened to place `arr` in memory just after `c` in memory, so the statement `*arr = 'a';` wrote `'a'` into `arr`. This will not happen in all C implementations. You got “lucky.”
- After the write of `'a'` into `arr`, `arr` is pointing somewhere, although we do not know where. Let’s call this location `x`.
- The statements `arr++;` and `*arr = 'b';` wrote `'b'` to the location `x+1`.
- The statements `arr++;` and `*arr = 'c';` wrote `'c'` to the location `x+2`.
- Then two `arr--;` statements returned `arr` to point to `x`. So `arr[1]` is the character at `x+1`, which is `'b'`, and `arr[2]` is `'c'`. Passing these to printf to be printed with “%c” prints “b” and “c”.

In the second version of the program, when `arr[0]` is passed to `printf`:

- The value of `arr` is the value that was formed by writing `'a'` into one of its bytes. This is some “random” address, pointing to no location we have controlled. Apparently there is a 0 character there, or some other non-printing character, so, when `arr[0]` is passed to `printf`, nothing is printed.
- Passing `arr[1]` and `arr[2]` print “b” and “c” because the code wrote `'b'` and `'c'` to those locations.

Comment: Good answer (+1).  Note that, strictly speaking, the behavior is undefined as soon as you do `arr++`, even without dereferencing it.  See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6566975/768469).  (Compilers can and do assume you are not doing this sort of thing and optimize accordingly.)

Comment: @Nemo: The first `arr++` is safe. You are allowed to point one beyond the last element of an array, and a single object acts as an array of one element. The first undefined operation in the code is the assignment into that location.

Answer (score 6):

`arr` is not equivalent to `arr[0]`, since `arr[0]` **dereferences** the array. The correct equivalent would be `&arr[0]`.

By the way, what you're doing invokes undefined behavior, since after incrementing `arr`, it points to an invalid memory location - originally it points to a **single character,** so you can't assume there's anything after it.

Comment: And if what's after it is `arr`, there could be great fun as `*arr = 'a'` changes the address (creating a wild pointer) and the subsequent writes don't just trash locals, but memory locations throughout the program.

Comment: @H2CO3 Ok if so, ie, if arr is not equal to arr[0]. then how arr+1 is printing same value as arr[1] ?

Comment: @KuntalBasu the keyword is undefined behavior. This program is not guaranteed to do anything meaningful.

Answer (score 6):

This is just undefined behavior - `arr++; *arr = 'a';` is illegal because `arr` points to a single `char`. Anything can happen.

Comment: The first `arr++` is legal since you may point one after the end of the array (and a single `char` is considered an array of length one for the purposes of pointer arithmetic). The subsequent ones, and the writes `*arr = x;` are undefined behaviour.

Comment: @DanielFischer yes, that's why I included the assignment.

Comment: This is undefined behavior as well: `printf("\narr 1 = %c",arr);` since the actual type (after promotion) of an argument to a varargs function is different from what is decoded.

Comment: Yes I understand this is not legal, then why arr[1] and arr[2] is printing b & c?

Comment: @KuntalBasu because anything can happen... that's what undefined behavior means.

Comment: @LuchianGrigore: Saying “Anything can happen” (according to the C standard) is not an answer to the question “Why did this happen?” The C standard is not the **only** specification that governs the behavior of computers, and there are reasons that the observed behavior happened.

Comment: @EricPostpischil yes Eric that's what I want to know, I know its a unsafe program, but in C or every programming language everything happens for a logic behind it. I can not assume it random behavior because it is happening every time I run the program.

Comment: Ok, I'm not going to get into a debate over "how undefined is undefined". IMO, it's just stupid asking "why is this illegal code behaving like this". Mind you, this isn't implementation-defined behavior, so you could try to make sense of what the compiler is doing, but pure undefined behavior. If you want to know how it works, produce legal code that exibits the issue. Otherwise, there's no point to it.

Comment: @LuchianGrigore: This is not “illegal” code, since neither law nor the C standard prohibits a person from passing this code to the C compiler. And there are specifications that fully define the behavior: A C compiler itself is built from source code, and the compilers that compile it and the specifications of the machines it runs on and produce output for specify the resulting behavior.

Comment: @LuchianGrigore: Given a specification of the compiler ideone.com uses and the machine it runs on, certainly we could determine why this particular segmentation fault occurred. But why bother? How would that help anybody learn? The case asked about in this question is interesting because “a” is printed when `arr` is passed to `printf`. That is, a completely wrong call was made, but the “right” character was printed. Something did not just go wrong, something coincided in a way that is misleading to somebody who is learning. There is an opportunity for education here.